# react-select onChange event does not render with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

i'm using the select-react library --> https://react-select.com/home

i have managed to mapped options to the individual items i will need from itemList. the dropdown do register the selected option, however my end goal is such that my bar chart renders the correct data of the selected option.

```
/**
 * Produces a filter list for item sales cards
 * @param {*} props
 * @returns the filter list of item names along with their ids
 */

export const ItemSelection = (props) => {
  const { onChangeValue, itemList } = props;

  if (itemList.length === 0) return <></>;

  return (
    <UncontrolledDropdown>
     <Select
        options={itemList.map((item) => {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item,
            key: item.itemID,
          };
        })}
        onChange={(item)=>onChangeValue(item)}
        placeholder="ITEM"
      />
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );
};
```

itemSelection is being used here:

```
  const [itemID = '1', setItemID] = useState('1');
  const [itemName = '', setItemName] = useState('');
  const [itemListID = [], setItemListID] = useState([]);

  <ItemSelection
      onChangeValue={(item) => {
         setItemID(item.itemID);
         setItemName(item.name);
       }}
        itemList={itemListID}
    />
```

onChangeValue is the one registering the option selected to the barchart. Is there anyway to map onChangeValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what argument you're actually expecting from the parent element that uses ItemSelection. That said, it also looks like Select takes a function that takes an action of type string and the option value as the second argument. The selected value would then come in the second argument.

Something along the lines of of the below code is what you need if all you care about is the value. On that note, you will get the selected string value passed to `onChangeValue` which I imagine is what you want without seeing the function definition from an ancestor component.

**Updated:**

The select code can take the entire option object as the second parameter.

```js
export const ItemSelection = (props) => {
  const { onChangeValue, itemList } = props;

  if (itemList.length === 0) return null;

  return (
    <UncontrolledDropdown>
      <Select
        options={itemList.map((item) => ({
          label: item.name,
          value: item.name, // note a change from your code here; it would have been an object otherwise
          key: item.itemID,
        }))}
        onChange={(item)=>onChangeValue(item)}
        placeholder="ITEM"
      />
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );
};
```

In the parent component

```js
  // note the changes here where I deleted the assignments
  const [itemID, setItemID] = useState('1');
  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState('');
  const [itemListID, setItemListID] = useState([]);

  <ItemSelection
    onChangeValue={(option) => {
      setItemID(option.key);
      setItemName(option.value);
    }}
    itemList={itemListID}
  />
```

Comment: ItemSelection is actually getting its state set in another component. i have revised my question with the relevant codes!

Comment: So what I mentioned above is still relevant but your parent is expecting something of the item type but you're getting an option type in the onChange in the child component. That said, the code can be fixed in a few ways which I'll try to address.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `itemListID` at the parent level? In addition, what are the values that your bar chart requires, the `itemListID`?

Comment: the bar chart requires the item ID, time(frequency) and the item sales data of the particular item selected. right now after following your suggested answer i'm still getting this error --> TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemID' of undefined.

Comment: The error lies in your definition here `const [itemListID = [], setItemListID] = useState([]);`. You try to access an array of array inside your .map code. This question is starting to deal a lot less with state and more with the overall code.

Comment: With the above code, the code should not have those runtime errors anymore. Problem is, itemListID is an empty list and your options won't render. So the next question is, where are you getting the available options that will eventually be selected?

Comment: thank you so much!!! i changed value:item to value: item.name and its finally passing item.